# Где найти грамматический словарь русского языка А. А. Зализняка?

Tags: база-данных, словари, поиск-данных

Нужен словарь А. А. Зализняка в виде **.dbf** или **.mdb**, или любой другой БД. Нашел в **.txt** возникла проблема *логической модели* словаря. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно взять словарь в нужном формате или подскажите идею по логической модели.

Comment: вот что-то нащупал, но не уверен - это вам нужно или нет.

Comment: Там пароль на dbf файле

Comment: это я не проверял. Нашел [вот тут][1], файл zaliznia.exe (самораспаковывающийся архив). Посмотрите сами на том ресурсе, может я чего не заметил.

 И не очень понятно, почему мой комментарий в ответ перевели.

   [1]:http://starling.rinet.ru/downl.php?lan=ru

Answer (score 1):

Скачать данные словаря можно по ссылке:

- https://github.com/gramdict/zalizniak-2010

Описание «логической модели», т. е. структуры словаря и значений спецсимволов:

- https://gramdict.ru/contents

Для использования словаря в коммерческих целях нужно заключить лицензионный договор с правообладателем (контакты по ссылкам выше).